# Python Pandas Looking up column value with multiple criteria and assign results to new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have what may be a fairly simple question.

I have a dataframe with employee information all the way up to the CTO. I am trying to for any employees with a vacant supervisor to have their supervisor's position number be replaced with that supervisor's bosses position number in a new column. One constraint I have to work with is the data is by month so I need to make sure the data would match for each of its respective month chunk.

I have been deleting a lot of my attempts at solving this as I have worked on it for the past few hours. I have attempted so far multiple .loc indexing, making a key value pair for supervisor position and vacant positions, and a simple if statement and that failed as well.

```
if df1['supervisor'] == 'vacant':
    df1['Non-Vacant-SuperPosnNbr'] = df1['SuperPosnNbr']
else:
    df1['Non-Vacant-SuperPosnNbr'] = df1['Non-Vacant-SuperPosnNbr']
```

For the example data I included what the desired outcome column would be, "Non-Vacant-SuperPosnNbr".

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Emp Name': {0: 'Emp 1',  1: 'Emp 2',  2: 'Emp 3',  3: 'Emp 4',  4: 'Emp 5',  5: 'vacant',  6: 'Emp 1',  7: 'Emp 2',  8: 'Emp 3',  9: 'Emp 4',  10: 'Emp 5',  11: 'Emp 6',  12: 'Emp 1',  13: 'Emp 2',  14: 'Emp 3',  15: 'Emp 4',  16: 'Emp 5',  17: 'vacant'},
 'EmplID': {0: 1.0,  1: 2.0,  2: 3.0,  3: 4.0,  4: 5.0,  5: '',  6: 1.0,  7: 2.0,  8: 3.0,  9: 4.0,  10: 5.0,  11: 6.0,  12: 1.0,  13: 2.0,  14: 3.0,  15: 4.0,  16: 5.0,  17: ''},
 'Title': {0: 'Data Analyst',  1: 'Data Analyst',  2: 'Director 2',  3: 'CTO',  4: 'Data Analyst',  5: 'Director 1',  6: 'Data Analyst',  7: 'Data Analyst',  8: 'Director 2',  9: 'CTO',  10: 'Data Analyst',  11: 'Director 1',  12: 'Data Analyst',  13: 'Data Analyst',  14: 'Director 2',  15: 'CTO',  16: 'Data Analyst',  17: 'Director 1'},
 'Position Nbr': {0: 10,  1: 11,  2: 12,  3: 13,  4: 14,  5: 15,  6: 10,  7: 11,  8: 12,  9: 13,  10: 14,  11: 15,  12: 10,  13: 11,  14: 12,  15: 13,  16: 14,  17: 15}, 
'Supervisor': {0: 'vacant',  1: 'Emp 4',  2: 'Emp 4',  3: 'Emp 4',  4: 'Emp 3',  5: 'Emp 4',  6: 'Emp 6',  7: 'Emp 4',  8: 'Emp 4',  9: 'Emp 4',  10: 'Emp 3', 11: 'Emp 4',  12: 'vacant',  13: 'vacant',  14: 'Emp 4', 15: 'Emp 4', 16: 'Emp 3', 17: 'Emp 4'},
 'Supervisor Position Nbr': {0: 15, 1: 12, 2: 13, 3: 13,4: 12, 5: 13,6: 15,7: 15,8: 13,9: 13,10: 12,11: 13,12: 15,13: 15,14: 13,15: 13,16: 12,17: 13},
'data date': {0: ('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), 1: ('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), 2: ('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), 3: ('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), 4: ('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), 5: ('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), 6: ('2021-10-01 00:00:00'), 7: ('2021-10-01 00:00:00'), 8: ('2021-10-01 00:00:00'), 9: ('2021-10-01 00:00:00'), 10: ('2021-10-01 00:00:00'), 11: ('2021-10-01 00:00:00'), 12: ('2021-09-01 00:00:00'), 13: ('2021-09-01 00:00:00'), 14: ('2021-09-01 00:00:00'), 15: ('2021-09-01 00:00:00'), 16: ('2021-09-01 00:00:00'),17: ('2021-09-01 00:00:00')}})
```

**Edit**: While I work on expanding the data frame below is a simpler explanation of what I am trying to accomplish.

For every month:
Check each employee's supervisor position for vacancy.
If their supervisor's position is vacant lookup their supervisor's boss and assign that to the original employee in a new column. Else use the original supervisor in the new column.
Note it is possible for multiple supervisor positions in a row to be vacant.

So for 10/1/21 If Bob's Supervisor is vacant the new column will show Jane as his Supervisor.
But for 11/1/21 Bob's supervisor will be Alice.

The original dataset has 18k~ rows across a rolling year if that matters.

I have updated the example and below this is the expected output:

```
import pandas as pd
expected_df = pd.DataFrame({'Emp Name': {0: 'Emp 1', 1: 'Emp 2',  2: 'Emp 3',  3: 'Emp 4',  4: 'Emp 5',  5: 'vacant',  6: 'Emp 1',  7: 'Emp 2',  8: 'Emp 3',  9: 'Emp 4',  10: 'Emp 5',  11: 'Emp 6',  12: 'Emp 1',  13: 'Emp 2',  14: 'Emp 3',  15: 'Emp 4',  16: 'Emp 5',  17: 'vacant'},
 'EmplID': {0: 1.0,  1: 2.0,  2: 3.0,  3: 4.0,  4: 5.0,  5: '',  6: 1.0,  7: 2.0,  8: 3.0,  9: 4.0,  10: 5.0,  11: 6.0,  12: 1.0,  13: 2.0,  14: 3.0,  15: 4.0,  16: 5.0,  17: ''}, 'Title': {0: 'Data Analyst',  1: 'Data Analyst',  2: 'Director 2',  3: 'CTO',  4: 'Data Analyst',  5: 'Director 1',  6: 'Data Analyst',  7: 'Data Analyst',  8: 'Director 2',  9: 'CTO',  10: 'Data Analyst',  11: 'Director 1',  12: 'Data Analyst',  13: 'Data Analyst',  14: 'Director 2',  15: 'CTO',  16: 'Data Analyst',  17: 'Director 1'},
 'Position Nbr': {0: 10,  1: 11,  2: 12,  3: 13,  4: 14,  5: 15,  6: 10,  7: 11,  8: 12,  9: 13,  10: 14,  11: 15,  12: 10,  13: 11,  14: 12,  15: 13,  16: 14,  17: 15},
 'Supervisor': {0: 'vacant',  1: 'Emp 4',  2: 'Emp 4',  3: 'Emp 4',  4: 'Emp 3',  5: 'Emp 4',  6: 'Emp 6',  7: 'Emp 4',  8: 'Emp 4',  9: 'Emp 4',  10: 'Emp 3',  11: 'Emp 4',  12: 'vacant',  13: 'vacant',  14: 'Emp 4',  15: 'Emp 4',  16: 'Emp 3',  17: 'Emp 4'},
 'Supervisor Position Nbr': {0: 15,  1: 12,  2: 13,  3: 13,  4: 12,  5: 13,  6: 15,  7: 15,  8: 13,  9: 13,  10: 12,  11: 13,  12: 15,  13: 15,  14: 13,  15: 13,  16: 12,  17: 13},
 'non_vacant super_posn_nbr': {0: 13,  1: 12,  2: 13,  3: 13,  4: 12,  5: 13,  6: 15,  7: 15,  8: 13,  9: 13,  10: 12,  11: 13,  12: 13,  13: 13,  14: 13,  15: 13,  16: 12,  17: 13},
 'non_vacant_supervisor empid': {0: 4,  1: 2,  2: 4,  3: 4,  4: 3,  5: 4,  6: 6,  7: 6,  8: 4,  9: 4,  10: 3,  11: 4,  12: 4,  13: 4,  14: 4,  15: 4,  16: 3,  17: 4},
 'data date': {0: ('2021-11-01 00:00:00'),  1: ('2021-11-01 00:00:00'),  2: ('2021-11-01 00:00:00'),  3: ('2021-11-01 00:00:00'),  4: ('2021-11-01 00:00:00'),  5: ('2021-11-01 00:00:00'),  6: ('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),  7: ('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),  8: ('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),  9: ('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),  10: ('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),  11: ('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),  12: ('2021-09-01 00:00:00'),  13: ('2021-09-01 00:00:00'),  14: ('2021-09-01 00:00:00'),  15: ('2021-09-01 00:00:00'),  16: ('2021-09-01 00:00:00'),  17: ('2021-09-01 00:00:00')}})
```

Sorry for the size of the post. I am trying to be as thorough as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you should be able to use `Series.mask()` to select all the values from a Series that match a condition (`Supervisor == 'Vacant'`), or NaN otherwise, and forward fill:

```
df1['Non-Vacant-SuperPosnNbr'] = df1['SuperPosnNbr'].mask(df1['Supervisor'].eq('Vacant')).ffill()
```

Output:

```
>> df1
  EmpName EmpId         title  PosnNbr Supervisor SuperPosnNbr  data date Non-Vacant-SuperPosnNbr
0     Bob     1  Data Analyst       15      Alice           44  11/1/2021                      44
1    Jane     4           CTO       35                          11/1/2021                        
2   Alice     3    Director 1       44       Jane           35  11/1/2021                      35
3     Bob     1  Data Analyst       15     Vacant           44  10/1/2021                      35
4    Jane     4           CTO       35                          10/1/2021                        
5  Vacant          Director 1       44       Jane           35  10/1/2021                      35
6     Bob     1  Data Analyst       15       Phil           44  09/1/2021                      44
7    Jane     4           CTO       35                          09/1/2021                        
8    Phil     6    Director 1       44       Jane           35  09/1/2021                      35
```

Comment: Tank you for responding! This is filling in the Non-Vacant positions but not corresponding supervisor's position numbers and especially not for each month.

Comment: Hmm. Will you please enhance your sample dataframe to account for those two conditions for me? Thank you :)

Comment: Sure, let me figure out the best way to expand it without making the dataframe too large. 
 I added a simplified version of what I am trying to accomplish to see if that helps. Thank you again!